# git clean removes empty directories

Tags: git

This is what I did:

```
$ git status
# I see some files *and* directories (some tracked, some not) which I really wanted to discard
$ git clean -xd
```

And I am surprised to see that git removes some other directories, which were not shown in `git status`. After an initial schock (this was my `/etc` in one of my production hosts) I realize that they were not listed by git because they were empty directories (so not a big deal, just `mkdir` them - hoping to get permissions right). Which is fine, but:

Why on earth does git not consider empty directories when doing `git status`, but does consider them when doing `git clean`? This is very annoying (and dangerous)!

Comment: git only tracks file. If you want to track a folder, putting a `.gitignore` file in the folder is a common way to achieve it. Git clean returns the repository to the state known to git (files only).

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: Might even be a "hidden" duplicate.

Comment: If you truly want to see what `git clean` removes, run it with the `-n` (`--dry-run`) option. See the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean).

Comment: I am not asking how to add empty dirs (I already know that). I am just complaining (and hoping to be corrected) why are `git clean` and `git status` not consistent wrt empty directories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already seem to know: You can't add empty directories in git (If not [see the FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F)).

`git status` effectivly tells you which changes you can *add* and *commit*. So, even if it would be possible for `git status` to display empty directories, this would be highly confusing for the user.

> Why can I see this directory but not track it?

---

[`git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) on the other hand removes everything which **isn't tracked**. Using the `-d` option also tells `clean` to remove *untracked directories*.

But what defines an *untracked directory*?

As we learned, git doesn't track directories, it tracks files (or more specific file contents). In turn this means that an *untracked director* is nothing else but a directory which doesn't contain any *tracked files*. This applies for the `build` folder you ignore with multiple hundred of files, as it does for the empty `tmp` folder, you created earlier and forgot about.

If you want to make sure that `git clean` doesn't remove anything you want to keep, you should use the `-n` (`--dry-run`) option ([which is described in the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)). This tells you about all files `git clean` will remove.

To ensure that you don't forget `-n` (`--dry-run`) you can create an alias.

```
git config --global alias.status-clean "clean --dry-run"
```

Which you can now easily use like `git status-clean -dx` to display all files which would be removed by a `git clean -dx` call.

---

**TL;DR:** Don't use `git status` to see what `git clean -d` will remove. Use `git clean -d --dry-run`.

Comment: Thanks, but not convinced. `git status` can already report non-trackable files (with `--ignored`), so it makes sense to have a `--all` flag, and `git status` could just have another section for "Empty non-trackable directories". Basically, the reporting tool (`git status`) and the acting tool (in this case `git clean`) are using a different set of files/directories, which is not cool at all. You would not be very happy if `ls` could not list empty directories but `rm` could very well delete them. Luckily there is the `ls -a` form.

Comment: I do not like to use a tool which is intended for writing to the filesystem (`git clean`) to perform a reporting operation, simply because it is too easy to make a mistake and forget the `--dry-run` (ever done a `^R` to search for your last command?). Reporting with a *read-only* tool, acting with a *read-write* tool. But if they are not consistent ...

Comment: I disagree strongly. You are comparing two completly different situations. `git status --ignored` doesn't report **non-trackable files** it reports **trackable files** which you **explicitly choose** not to track. An empty directory is **not trackable**. `git status` is the reporting too for everything which involves the **tracking** of files (`add`, `commit`, `diff` etc.); `git clean` on the other hand removes everything you **don't track**, be it **on purpose** or because git **can't track** it. You're expecting the wrong tool to do the job.

Comment: Which is the corresponding reporting tool for git clean then? I mean, a read-only reporting tool, which can not wreak havoc if I forget a command-line flag? My point is that it *should* be `git status`

Comment: As I said, `git status` is for **tracking** and `git clean` for **not tracking**. You can easily create an alias `git config --global alias.status-clean "clean --dry-run"` and use this.